# Using image URL which has dashes in it

Tags: android, url

I'm trying to download images from a website and my code is working fine in most cases, but I can't download from this URL http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/Steiny’s%20Blues%20-%20Such%20Sweet%20Thunder.jpg

The difference between this and the other URLs is that this one has a dash. I'm fairly certain this is the problem. Is there a way around this?

My error is `java.io.filenotfoundexception`

My initial code was:

```
imgLink = "http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/" + Show + ".jpg";
imgLink = imgLink.replace(" ", "%20");
```

This gave me links like: http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/The%20Atlantics.jpg
which works, but this didn't work for the link I posted at the top.

So now I've tried:

```
try {
    Show = URLEncoder.encode(Show, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
imgLink = "http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/" + Show + ".jpg";
```

Which doesnt work for any of my links, such as http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/The+Atlantics.jpg

If you copy and paste the link at the start of this post into your browser it will work, so it is just not working on Android.

Comment: Looks like the `'` is breaking it, rather than the `-`. Have you urlencoded it?

Comment: I think maybe we need to see your code. What do you think?

Comment: I've edited my post to include code - also tried Michael's answer - didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imgLink = "http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/Steiny%E2%80%99s%20Blues%20-%20Such%20Sweet%20Thunder.jpg"

working fine for me, tested it, replace the characters thus accordingly     and `'`.

`-` is fine.

Comment: Thats great, all working now. I'm just using .replace to change " " into %20 and "'" into %E2%80%99. Is there a nicer way to do this? and where did you find the %E2%80%99 code from?

Comment: Just copied the url you mentioned in my browser's addres bar and opened the image,  then again copied from there it becomes `http://www.liveandlocal.org.uk/images/ShowPics/Steiny%E2%80%99s%20Blues%20-%20Such%20Sweet%20Thunder.jpg` .  Modern Browser's automatically add `http://` in beginning and replaces spaces and these spl characters when you copy form them...

Answer (score 0):

Your url contains letters which are not suited for urls (`'` in this case).
You can encode your url as the following:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(normalUrl, "UTF-8");
```

[URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)